# Why does this sometimes mean base?

Tags: c#

Given

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal constructor called");
    }
    public virtual void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("animal speaks");
    }
}

public class Dog: Animal
{
    public Dog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog constructor called");
        this.Speak();
    }
    public override void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dog speaks");
  base.Speak();
    }
}
```

`this.Speak()` calls `Dog.Speak()`.  Remove `Speak()` from dog and suddenly `this.Speak()` calls `Animal.Speak()`.  Why does `this` behave this way?  In other words, why does `this` mean `base` or `this`?

To me, an explicit call to `base.Speak()` makes more sense.  Especially when speak is not virtual, surprisingly Speak() is still called when `virtual` is removed.  I understand IS-A relationships from an OO sense, but I can't wrap my head around this specific problem in C#.  This gets especially annoying when people write God class UI's (practically every business does).  I'm looking for "Speak()" inside "this" when I should be looking at "base".

Comment: Calling virtual methods in a constructor is a no-no.

Comment: What behavior will be expected with `base`, when there will be `class Doberman : Dog` and `Dog` still won't overload Animal's `Speak`?

Comment: @leppie - I assume that's because of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclases automatically inherit behavior from their base classes.  If you don't do anything other than inherit `Dog` from `Animal` then `this.Speak()` and `base.Speak()` both reference the version of `Speak()` that was implemented in `Animal`.

Where special things start happening is if `Dog` overrides `Speak()`.  This is not possible unless `Speak()` is `virtual`.  (The `virtual` keyword doesn't control inheritance, it controlls overriding.)

Only when `Dog` overrides `Speak()` does `base.Speak()` do something special: In that case, calling `Speak()` (or `this.Speak()`) will execute `Dog`'s implementation, because it `override`s `Animal`'s implementation.  This is where `base` becomes useful: it allows you to get around this behavior by specifying that you want to execute the base class's implementation rather than the override.

A common use of this style is in constructors.  For example:

```
public class Animal
{
    private readonly string _name;
    public Animal() : this("Animal") { }
    protected Animal(string name) { _name = name; }
    public void Speak() { Console.WriteLine(_name + " speaks"); }
}

public class NamedAnimal : Animal
{
    public NamedAnimal(name) : base(name) { }
}

// usage:
(new Animal()).Speak();  // prints "Animal speaks"
(new NamedAnimal("Dog")).Speak();     // prints "Dog speaks"
```

In this example, `NamedAnimal` doesn't have access to the `_name` field, but it is still able to set it indirectly by calling the base class's constructor.  But the base class's signature is the same as one in the base class, so it has to be specified using `base`.

With non-constructors it's also useful to get at behavior that's not otherwise accessible.  For example, if `Animal.Speak` were virtual then we could use an override to tack behavior onto it rather than simply replacing it:

```
public class NamedAnimal : Animal
{
    public NamedAnimal(name) : base(name) { }
    public override Speak()
    {
        Console.Write("The animal named ");
        base.Speak();
    }
}

// usage:
(new NamedAnimal("Dog")).Speak();  // Writes "The animal named Dog speaks"
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not that. Its that if there *is* a speak method within `dog`, then it is an *`override`* of the base method. If it isn't there, then calling dogInstance.Speak will look for the Speak() method in any of Dog's base classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the very fundamental points of OO. If you don't provide an override, then the parent method is used.

Also, even if you remove `virtual`, `Dog.Speak` is called because you're not accessing `this` polymorphically.

Answer (score 1):

`this` means `this` and nothing else.

Just in your first example you have an override for `Speak(..)` function, so `this` call that one.

In second case, istead, there is no any override, so it "climbs" on derivation tree and pick the first suitable function. In your case that one is `Speak(..)` of the `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net has the `MyClass` keyword to do just that (as opposed to the `My` keyword, which is the equivalent of `this` in C#).  Unfortunately, there is no `MyClass` equivalent keyword in C#.